# Can't attach a database, Error = 'A file activation error ocurred...'

Tags: sql-server, docker

I'm running SQL Server 2017 in a Docker container and I can't attach a database to it.

First I copied the `.MDF, .NDF, .LDF` files to the container running

```
docker cp /local/folder/of/my/files/db.mdf my-container:db.mdf
```

(same for 3 files), so all the 3 files are in the root of my container.

After that I gave full permission to my files ( `chmod 777` ).

I connected to the container (`docker exec -it my-container "bash"`) and run `ls` to see if the 3 files if really there, then I run `sqlcmd` and connect to the database.

I run:

```
CREATE DATABASE PEDIDOS ON
( FILENAME = N'DB.MDF' ),
( FILENAME = N'DB_INDEX.NDF' ),
( FILENAME = N'DB_LOG.NDF' )
FOR ATTACH;
GO
```

And get this error message:

> Msg 5105, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   A file activation error occurred. The physical file name 'DB.MDF' may be incorrect. Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry the operation.

I've tried many alt forms like without the N, with a / before the file name (like `(FILENAME = N'/DB.MDF')`), without the `.NDF` file and nothing works.

This files was generated by a SQL Server 2016, is this a compatibility error? Like, I have read so much questions with this same error and all of that the answer was a permissions error on `.mdf` file (but I really don't know how to give this permission).

Comment: Typically, SQL Server doesn't store its data files in the root directory - you might need to move those files to where SQL Server keeps its files (where you find other `.mdf` files) , and then try again

Comment: Thank you so much, i has forgotten this.

Answer (score 1):

Mrs marc_s aswered very well, so if you are getting this same error the aswer is:

Move the files to the data folder (by default is `/var/opt/mssql/data`) and run

```
USE master;
GO

CREATE DATABASE U_DB ON
(FILENAME = N'/var/opt/mssql/data/db.MDF'),
(FILENAME = N'/var/opt/mssql/data/dbLOG.LDF'),
(FILENAME = N'/var/opt/mssql/data/dbINDEX.NDF')
FOR ATTACH;
GO
```